# C++ how to use std::function with overloaded operators of different return types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to use the standard `std::function` with custom overloaded operators. However applying `std::logical_and` to my `Test` class with a `string` parameter is not working in this situation.

```
class Test {
public:
    std::string value;

    Test(std::string cvalue) : value(cvalue) {}

    std::string operator&& (const std::string& rhs) const {
        if (rhs == value) {
            return "true";
        }
        return "false";
    }
};

int main() {
    Test test("hey");
    std::string out = std::logical_and<std::string>()(test, "hey");
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the proper way of achieving this? My expected output is `"true"`

Comment: *"use the standard `std::function`"*. You don't use `std::function<Sig>` actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `std::logical_and<>` to allow deduction for both arguments and return type:

```
std::string out = std::logical_and<>()(test, "hey");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64fb6f02c64ba081)